# Docker no monta los volumenes en mi contenedor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

por algun motivo mi docker-desktop no esta montando los volumenes que le indico.
Uso unas imagenes que tengo hechas para laravel php 8.1 con xdebug y funcionan bien.

Anteriormente ya cree esto e hice estas practicas de dockerizacion en proyectos sin problemas, asi que descarto 100% cualquier problema con las imagenes que trabajo.

Tambien he probado a instalar diferentes versiones y nada.

Asi esta hecho el mount :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo suelo poner la app en cuestion en el dir `/var/www/html/app` y siempre me va bien.

He estado resinstalando y todo el docker, con diferentes versiones, desde la ultima a unas mas antiguas. Dudo que sea ya docker.

Me queda el tema de permisos o algo. Tambien tengo añadido /home en la configuracion de directorios con permisos para poder crear volumenes :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los permisos que tengo en el proyecto son `775 jose:jose`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo usuario docker que no se si puede estar por ahi el problema, en algun tutorial vi que era buena practica, eso es lo unico que tengo sospecha, pero es algo recomendable no obligatorio

PD: De hecho tengo montado el mismo proyecto igual pero en otro PC con windows y funciona a la perfeccion. (Y los monte el mismo dia)

Comment: Era porque home lo tengo en una particion, le he dado permisos ara que lea /media/home y ya lo hace bien

Comment: El problema ya lo he puesto en los comentarios